# Spring URL fails authorization with User is not anonymous in WebExpressionV

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, basic-authentication

I am building a simple Spring boot application with spring security for learning with my own UserDetailService which returns a user object for authentication. I have the following code to configure the authorization but when i use my custom UserDetailService the authorization fails and the same works with inmemoryAuthentication or JDbcAuthentication.

The issue I am getting is that I always get the 403 forbidden error for users which require permission while I can easily access the home page so the authentication works but authorization has some issues.

I have listed the error and the code for this, hope someone can provide some clue on this. I have tried many different things like disabling csrf, using authority instead of role and vice-versa etc but nothing seems to work. The version of Spring is 2.3.1 with

Logs show the following Error

```
2020-07-27 14:49:43.128 DEBUG 13952 --- [http-nio-8091-exec-5] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@50390f54, returned: -1
2020-07-27 14:49:43.129 DEBUG 13952 --- [http-nio-8091-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

---

The code for the configure method and custom Userdetailservice are given below

```java
 /* The configure methods of the class SecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter */
    @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
              auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //add most restrictive at the top.
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    //.hasAuthority("USERS")
                    .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USERS")
                    //.hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","USERS")
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin();
    
        }
```

```java
/* My UserDetailService is simple that it just returns an object of hardcoded UserDetails */

    @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails user = new MyUserDetails(s);
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, looks like you forget to provide ListOfAuthority levels for particular user.

Comment: @AleksandrsRudzitis - I did add the list of authority for the user, it is hardcoded in MyUserDetails class and I created it using SimpleGrantedAuthority and giving ROLE_ADMIN authority to the user.